# Spelling Bee word randomizer

Tags: java, python, excel, database, random

I am a primary school teacher and want to create a program to randomly choose a word from a bank of spelling words that I will enter. I want to create this to insure that there can be no bias on the part of the judge choosing an easier or harder word due to personal feelings. I have no programming experience and I have tried to fins this information on google. I appreciate any help that you can offer.

Comment: nice. ill glad to help. but, using the command line would be ok for you?

Comment: Presumably you're going to be storing this bank of words in either a list or a set. In Python, the function [`random.choice`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/random.html#random.choice) will pick one out of that list or set for you. Most languages have something similar—if not builtin, then as an easily-found recipe or snippet. Honestly, inputting and saving and loading the bank of words is the hard part here (relatively speaking—it's still pretty easy), not choosing them at random.

Comment: This question is far too broad for Stack Overflow. This site is a good resource for specific, answerable problems, such as some specific code producing an unexpected result or a question about the difference between one algorithm and another. Big, broad, open-ended questions like these just don't fit our format, unfortunately.

Comment: Don't know how much knowledge you have of python, but I've quickly thrown this together and commented each line, so hopefully you will be able to understand it: Before using this program you must make a 'words.txt' file and type each word you would like to include on separate lines. The code: https://hastebin.com/gotufimabu.py

Answer (score 1):

If you've got excel, the easy way is to create a list on a tab (name the tab List). Create a new tab called retrieve and in a cell of that tab, enter the following formula. I assume you have 250 words. If you don't, change the number 250 to your number of words in both spots where it occurs.

```
=index(List!A1:A250,randbetween(1,250))
```

Everytime you hit the `F9` key, you will get a fresh word, though this method doesn't guarantee no repeats.